# Downloading a File from URL?

Tags: google-chrome, download, flash

Due to updates and new restrictions on our Network Google Chrome, I cant extract SWFs and add them to iframes, chrome used to download an swf when say I opened this link: Ex: [papasfreezaria_coolmath.swf](https://www.coolmath-games.com/sites/cmatgame/files/games/papasfreezeria_coolmath.swf)
But now it just opens a mini Iframe and loads the game, all sites seem to be doing this, and I want to download the SWF, I tried grabbing it via Network Debugger, also tried using Sources in DevTools on chrome, edge, and IE, but none would show the swf and give me the option to save it.

If theres a method to downloading a URL I would appreciate it, I also run lots of codepen zip files and webAPIs through file stream pipelines, and a method to directly download the zip file url would be amazing.

Comment: Look into the command line program `wget` or `curl`.

Comment: I need a web based answer.. Im not good with command line, and I dont have access to cmd prompt and other such programs.. Im just a JS coder looking for a simple web-explanation.. wouldnt my problem be solvable by sending the url to a SRC link in javascript, turning it into a file stream... then downloading it via js??

Comment: Your problem is extremely and quickly solvable by taking about 15 minutes and learning a couple commands.  If you are a Javascript coder honestly this shouldn't be much of a challenge.  However you can look into a Windows program called WinWGet, but you'll still need to learn about `wget`'s many options.

Comment: I repeat @LawrenceC  I. Can. Not. Use. Command. Programs... They. Are. BLOCKED.

Comment: So PLEASE if you can, Id like help with a Web Based option.

Comment: Now if theres a Java based option, Then we can make some progress.

Comment: @TaylorSpark , welcome.  I hope that we can help you learn how to ask good Questions, first of yourself, then of others.  On SuperUser and other StackExchange sites, it's best to put all limitations in the Question body, rather than in comments.  Visitors then see the scope, such as "I'm in a library, can't install programs, can't run CMD, and only have access to Chrome/Edge/IE".  More importantly, every visitor later will see a straightforward question, with some straightforward answers below.  That way, it's easy for future people to search for it.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Thankyou for your input, I will try my best to make answers and questions more static and more... "Accessible" if you will :D

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome 74 on Mac 10.14 and Windows 10, when I paste https://www.coolmath-games.com/sites/cmatgame/files/games/papasfreezeria_coolmath.swf into the URL bar, it immediately downloads.  It asks if I want to keep the dangerous file, which saves the SWF.

In Firefox 66 on Mac 10.14, when I paste the link into the URL bar, it presents "Run Adobe Flash".  I can right-click and choose Save Page As, which saves the SWF.  In Firefox 66 on Windows, when I paste the link into the URL bar, it immediately presents a "Save File" dialog.  This saves the SWF.

In the circumstance where I visit a page and a file is shown as a direct link, I can right-click on it and choose 'Save Link As'.  This saves the SWF.

In the circumstance where the file's URL is present if I Show Source or Page Source, I can then paste it into the URL bar, which is the same as the first example.

In the circumstance where the SWF is hidden behind a Javascript AdBlocker-Blocker or some authentication method, then you will have to figure out the specific way around that specific problem.

Comment: Chris, the admins of my network enforced Flash Enabled for all sites, so it automatically plays. Ill either rip it from the OFFICIAL site, which is way easier, when I get home. OR Ill simply just use the older version of it I have saved in my online drive.